# create a PCRE expression that matches exactly the strings described. strings that have exactly 3 vowels in any position

Tags: awk, grep

the vowels do not have to appear consecutively. The string bonfire should
match, but beak and yearbook should not.

I tried using

```
grep -P '([aeiouy][aeiouy]*){3}'
```

but it only seems to work when the vowels are consecutive.

Comment: I think you meant `grep -P '([aeiouy][^aeiouy]*){3}'`

Answer (score 3):

This job can be done easily using `awk` without using any regex. Just set field separator to one of the vowels and then make sure we have 4 fields:

```bash
awk -F '[aeiouy]' 'NF == 4' file
```

PS: `y` is not really a vowel but included because of your shown example.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[^aeiouy]` to match non-vowels. Put a sequence of these around each vowel pattern.

```bash
grep -x '[^aeiouy]*[aeiouy][^aeiouy]*[aeiouy][^aeiouy]*[aeiouy][^aeiouy]*' filename
```

Use the `-x` option to match the whole line, or anchor the regexp with `^` and `$`.

You don't need PCRE, this only uses traditional regexp patterns.

Comment: Or just `grep -xE '[^aeiouy]*([aeiouy][^aeiouy]*){3}' filename`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `-P` for Perl-compatible regular expressions.

If you want to match `exactly 3 vowels` using grep, you can use anchors and match 3 vowels surrounded by optional repetitions of the negated character class `[^aeiouy]*` matching any character except the vowels.

```
grep '^[^aeiouy]*\([aeiouy][^aeiouy]*\)\{3\}$' file
```

Or with `-E`

```
grep -E '^[^aeiouy]*([aeiouy][^aeiouy]*){3}$' file
```

---

If you want at least 3 vowels:

```
grep -E '([aeiouy][^aeiouy]*){2}[aeiouy]' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ echo 'bonfire' | awk 'gsub(/[aeiouy]/,"&")==3'
bonfire
$ echo 'beak' | awk 'gsub(/[aeiouy]/,"&")==3'
$ echo 'yearbook' | awk 'gsub(/[aeiouy]/,"&")==3'
$
```